# how to show the number of records from the first day to the last day in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to show the number of records from the first day to the last day in pandas.

I have an dataframe like this:

```
          day category  value
0  2022-07-01        A      1
1  2022-07-01        B      2
2  2022-07-03        A      3
3  2022-07-05        A      4
4  2022-07-07        B      5
5  2022-07-07        B      6
```

I want to put the value of category in column and show the number by date.
(I want to show the number of records by date from the first date to the last date.)

output may be :

```
          day  A  B
0  2022-07-01  1  1
1  2022-07-02  0  0
2  2022-07-03  1  0
3  2022-07-04  0  0
4  2022-07-05  1  0
5  2022-07-06  0  0
6  2022-07-07  0  2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `pd.crosstab` then `resample`

```
#df.day = pd.to_datetime(df.day)

out = pd.crosstab(df.day,df.category).resample('1D').first().fillna(0).reset_index()
Out[607]: 
category        day    A    B
0        2022-07-01  1.0  1.0
1        2022-07-02  0.0  0.0
2        2022-07-03  1.0  0.0
3        2022-07-04  0.0  0.0
4        2022-07-05  1.0  0.0
5        2022-07-06  0.0  0.0
6        2022-07-07  0.0  2.0
```

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.day,df.category).asfreq('D', fill_value=0).reset_index()` is a bit better imo~

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for either pandas pivot_table() or groupby():

```
rands = np.random.randint(0,3,10)
choice = np.random.choice(['A','B'],10)
dates = np.random.choice([date(2022,7,1),date(2022,7,2),date(2022,7,3),date(2022,7,4)],10)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[choice,rands]).T
df.index = dates

df
Out[3]: 
            0  1
2022-07-01  A  2
2022-07-04  B  2
2022-07-03  A  1
2022-07-02  A  0
2022-07-02  B  2
2022-07-03  B  0
2022-07-02  B  1
2022-07-04  A  2
2022-07-03  B  2
2022-07-03  B  1

   pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index, columns=df[0],aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
Out[6]: 
            1   
0           A  B
2022-07-01  1  0
2022-07-02  1  2
2022-07-03  1  3
2022-07-04  1  1

df.groupby([df.index,0]).count()
    Out[4]: 
                  1
               0   
    2022-07-01 A  1
    2022-07-02 A  1
               B  2
    2022-07-03 A  1
               B  3
    2022-07-04 A  1
               B  1
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it

```
df1 =df.groupby('Date')['category'].agg('value_counts').unstack(level= -1).resample('1D').first().fillna(0).reset_index()

df1
```

Output:

```
category Date    A   B
0   2022-07-01  1.0 1.0
1   2022-07-02  0.0 0.0
2   2022-07-03  1.0 0.0
3   2022-07-04  0.0 0.0
4   2022-07-05  1.0 0.0
5   2022-07-06  0.0 0.0
6   2022-07-07  0.0 2.0
```

Comment: You can no longer use `resample` after you reset the index. `resample` is meant to be used on a datetime index.

Comment: @BeRT2me Hey, thanks. It's working now. Actually, I was applying `resample('1D')`  before unstacking. Maybe that's why it was throwing me an error. And thanks for the above info. I didn't know about that.

Comment: Before unstacking you had a multiindex, which also doesn't play nicely with `resample`~